# Java - Print a raw text in dot matrix printer over the network (without a driver)

Tags: java, printing, dot-matrix

I need to print a series of formatted raw text using a Dot Matrix printer (I'm exploring printer in the lines of [Epson LQ-590](https://www.epson.co.in/24-Pin-Dot-Matrix-Printers/Epson-LQ-590-Dot-Matrix-Printer/p/C11C558062) from a Java application being run on a Linux server (container actually).

Since, I just need to print a raw text, I'm hoping to do this as directly (from the Java app) and minimally as possible, without using any driver of sorts. Epson website seems to provide only Windows driver only.

Say, I hook the printer to the network (using ethernet), assign it a static IP, can I (and if yes, howO feed the printer the text I want to be printed using the IP address and a port. Also, is the port something Printer usually assigns itself, do most of them listen to port 9100 or is it something that has to be configured?

I saw a few examples on SO where printer is configured as a OutputStream but it wasn't clear on the physical connectivity of the printer part.

Comment: You could try to configure a PPD file yourself for that printer or configure it as a generic text or postscript printer and then use it in Java.

But modern OSes require some form of driver to communicate. In the old days you could just print some non-visible ASCII characters and get your printer going but that's no longer the case unfortunately (or fortunately, since that wouldn't be great if a hacker gets into your machine)

Comment: @AminM How would I configure PPD file for the printer?

Comment: It's a unix file format you'd have to look that up in the linux documentation. I'm just pointing you in a possible direction.
You could also try with a similar printer if your particular printer is not available.